# SQL query count = 0/null

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following MySql table with ~19000 entries like this:

```
ID      USER        FIELD1         FIELD2         SOMEINT   ERROR
1       name1       null           null           null      missing...
2       name1       value1         value2         3         validated!
3       name1       value3         wrongvalue1    null      syntax
4       name2       wrongvalue2    value4         null      syntax
etc...................................................................
```

I would like to get a list like this:

```
USER    totalEntries     totalValid   totalMissing    totalSyntax
name1   3                1            1               1
name2   1                0            0               1
etc...................................................................
```

I have a query for every column like this:

```
select user, count(user) valid from table where 
someint is not null group by user limit 0, 20000;
(total valid entries)

select user, count(*) totalEntries from table group by user
limit 0, 20000; (total entries)

select user, count(*) totalMissing from table where field1 is null or
field2 is null group by user limit 0, 20000; (total Missing entrie)

select user, count(*) syntax from table where error like 'syntax%'
group by user limit 0, 20000 (syntaxerror entries)
```

The problem is that "group by" does not list the count(...) entries as

```
USER     valid
...
name3    0
```

So the 4 query results do not have the same rowcount. How can I solve this Problem?

Comment: What is `count(responsible)`? There is no 'responsible' in any of the data you showed before.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your example is not clear to me. Try to explain better, please.

Comment: Oh sorry. mixed responsible up with user... -> edit

Comment: Is there a table with the list of all the users???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to do this:

```
SELECT user, COUNT(*) as totalEntries, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN someint IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN field1 IS NULL OR field2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE WHEN error LIKE 'syntax%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM SomeTable
GROUP by user
```

1. User Name
2. Number of entries of the user
3. Number of entries of entries with some int different of `NULL`
4. Number of entries where `Error is`missing`
5. Number of entries where `ERROR` is `syntax`

PD: Maybe you want to add the `LIMIT 0,20000` at the end of the query. I didn't do that because I didn't get the purpose.

Comment: You're welcome but, Why did you use the limit? I'm a little bit curious

Comment: I was just trying this query out with MySQL Workbench and the default limit was at 1000. I know "quick and dirty" but I didn't have any time. ;)

Comment: Ok, :). Also you could remove the limit on File\Preferences.